# List all functions that are called in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone have a quick way/macro that lists all the functions that are used/referenced in an Excel sheet/worckbook ? Including addin functions (example : C#/C++ addin functions ).
Or, alternatively, a method that tells if a certain input function-name is called.

Comment: There's a formula tokenizer here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/12/05/formula-tokenizer/ that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Mods - feel free to delete this answer as it's essentially link-only. Perhaps I should know better, but I think this could be helpful to the OP]

I have a solution to this but it's proprietary so I can't release the source. However I'll describe the approach. It's *not* a quick way!

It's not easy to formulate a tokeniser for the Excel formula grammar. For one thing, you don't know the formula list in advance so you can't hard-wire them into the grammar. But the form of a formula in Excel is sufficiently well-defined to be able to tokenise it in a reasonably systematic manner.

Take a look at http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2004/12/excel_formula_p.html. This shows you how to tokenise an excel formula. Once you have a formula tokenised, you can extract the function names.

Comment: Anything simpler/quicker ?

Comment: Nope. It's really not trivial.